# Modified a file where a pipe was writing to

Tags: linux, unix, pipe

I have a large calculation running, and through a command like

```
./largecalculation > output
```

I have been saving the output of it. Accidentaly I modified the file output, and it seems that the pipe is not writing to it again. Where is the output going to, and is there a way to force it to continue writing to the file where it was writing to? I am afraid my linux internals are not good enough to understand what is really happening here, but maybe someone can help me with it. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly did you do ("I modified the file output")?

Comment: I wrote to the same filename with another process, so I basically deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

When "modifying the file output" you probably deleted the original `output` and created a new one.

On Linux, you can delete an open file. Filenames are stored in the directory, each name has a link to an "inode" which stores the file attributes and the links to the data blocks. Deleting the file removes the link, but if it's open, the inode remains. So there is hope.

So if `largecalculation` is still running, you can still recover the data using the inode.

First find the process id of `largecalculation`:

```
ps -u `whoami` | grep largecalculation
```

I'll refer to the returned number as `<pid>` from now.

You can find a symbolic link to the open files of each process in the `/proc` filesystem, even if the files were deleted:

```
ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd
```

You'll find an entry called `1` here, which is the standard output of `largecalculation`, probably along with a filename, like `output (deleted)`.

It's impossible to create a link to the inode, but you can save the file contents. The trick is to keep saving in the background until `largecalculation` finishes.

```
tail -f -n +1 /proc/<pid>/fd/1 >output1 &
```

This will run in the background. After `largecalculation` has finished, you can stop saving:

```
kill %1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has been a very good step in the right direction. Very interesting, this /proc pseudofilesystem. Unfortunately the file is in a nfs filesystem, and this will not work. It says "stale file handle", which makes sense in this context, of course. I can also not find an inode number:

COMMAND     PID  USER   FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
BufferAll 14130 username    1w  unknown   0,21               /net/home/path/to/file (deleted) (server.address:/net/home)

supposedly, there should be a .nfsXXXXX file somewhere for this, but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Too bad... I'm sorry.